# Accessing model field in ManyToMany relation in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am following the example in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

In this case, given a Person object, how can I access all the groups that Person is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access these with:

```
Group.objects.filter(members=my_person_object)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!